# Issues with Blazor and latest preview

Tags: c#, blazor

Blazor project having an issue with the render tree. I am using a project of Github I have updated the blazor reference to the latest.

But now I am getting the following error within Google Chrome.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame
>   (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder+DiffContext&
>   diffContext, System.Int32 frameIndex) <0x3564ae0 + 0x00082> in
>   :0  d.printErr @
>   blazor.webassembly.js:1

I updated to Preview 9 cause the fact the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree. Component seems to be removed on the version that is in the latest visual studio 2019 is this a known bug I don't see many articles about it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for anyone else the issue can be resolved using the following.

https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/46

Welcome to Blazor.